# Why does my header disappear from front page using fancyhdr?

Tags: fancyhdr

I am writing a letter and using `fancyhdr` to use a pdf file as a header.  It is a two page letter, and I have specified the header to be on both the first page as well as the subsequent pages.  Everything works fine, until I add a return address using `address`.  Then the header disappears from the first page.  Here is a working example

```
\documentclass{letter}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{url}
\urlstyle{same}

\geometry{headheight = .6in}
\fancypagestyle{firstpage}{\fancyhf{}\fancyhead[L]{\includegraphics[height=0.5in, keepaspectratio=true]{header.pdf}}}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{\fancyhf{}\fancyhead[L]{\includegraphics[height=0.5in, keepaspectratio=true]{header.pdf}}}
\pagestyle{plain}
\address{Joe Smith \\ 100 Main Street. \\ Chicago, IL 60610}

\begin{document}%

\begin{letter}{Department  \\ University of X\\ City, State Area Code}%

\opening{Dear Some Name,}

\lipsum{1:5}

\vspace{.5in}
\noindent Sincerely,
\vspace{.7in}

\noindent Joe Smith

\noindent Ph.D. Candidate

\noindent Department 

\noindent University 
\end{letter}%

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`letter.cls` contains the following lines (I only show the relevant part):

```
\newcommand*{\opening}[1]{\ifx\@empty\fromaddress
  \thispagestyle{firstpage}%
    {\raggedleft\@date\par}%
  \else  % home address
    \thispagestyle{empty}%
    {\raggedleft\begin{tabular}{l@{}}\ignorespaces
      \fromaddress \\*[2\parskip]%
      \@date \end{tabular}\par}%
  \fi
```

which show that when `\address` is used, the `empty` page style is used instead of `fitrspage`. In this case, to have the `plain` style also in the first page, you can simply `\let` the `empty` page style to be `plain`:

```
\documentclass{letter}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{url}
\urlstyle{same}

\geometry{headheight = .6in}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{\fancyhf{}\fancyhead[L]{\includegraphics[height=0.5in, keepaspectratio=true]{header.pdf}}}
\pagestyle{plain}
\address{Joe Smith \\ 100 Main Street. \\ Chicago, IL 60610}

\makeatletter
\let\ps@empty\ps@plain
\let\ps@firstpage\ps@plain
\makeatother

\begin{document}%

\begin{letter}{Department  \\ University of X\\ City, State Area Code}%

\opening{Dear Some Name,}

\lipsum{1:5}

\vspace{.5in}
\noindent Sincerely,
\vspace{.7in}

\noindent Joe Smith

\noindent Ph.D. Candidate

\noindent Department 

\noindent University 
\end{letter}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice that I also `\let` `\ps@firstpage` to be `\ps@plain` so (with economy of code) all pages will receive the `plain` style whether or not `\address` is used.

The `demo` option for `graphicx` simply replaces actual figures with black rectangles; do *not* use that option in your actual document.

Comment: @Philipp +1 to yours too; it uses one of my packages :-)

Comment: Thanks, adding your extra 4 lines of code was easy and worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `background` package to place the logo in all the pages of your document.

```
\documentclass{letter}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{url}
\urlstyle{same}
\usepackage{background}    % load the background package

\geometry{headheight = .6in}

% settings for the background package
\SetBgColor{black}
\SetBgScale{1}
\SetBgOpacity{1}
\SetBgAngle{0}
\SetBgContents{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node at (0,0.6\textheight) {\includegraphics[height=0.5in, keepaspectratio=true]{header.pdf}};
\end{tikzpicture}}

\pagestyle{empty}

\address{Joe Smith \\ 100 Main Street. \\ Chicago, IL 60610}

\begin{document}%

\begin{letter}{Department  \\ University of X\\ City, State Area Code}%

\opening{Dear Some Name,}

\lipsum{1:5}

\vspace{.5in}
\noindent Sincerely,
\vspace{.7in}

\noindent Joe Smith

\noindent Ph.D. Candidate

\noindent Department 

\noindent University 
\end{letter}%

\end{document}
```